# What alternatives exist to providing clients estimates for a software agency?

Tags: project-management

I work for a web development agency, and currently we bill clients by the hour, and provide estimates for each piece of work. Work is generally broken down into small chunks, with estimates being provided for each of these, rather than large pieces of work all at once.

We’re currently talking about trying to move away from this approach—everyone knows estimates are always wrong and no-one likes them, but they’re generally seen as a necessary evil.

I would be interested to hear any alternative approaches people have successfully used, ideally specifically in an agency environment where you are dealing with multiple clients daily.

Comment: *"Work is generally broken down into small chunks, with estimates being provided for each of these, rather than large pieces of work all at once."* -- can you clarify what you mean by this? Is the client paying for each small item individually or are they paying for a bunch of items together?

Comment: Against what do you define the alternatives? I mean, the alternative to giving estimates, is not giving estimates. The alternative to lies, is truth. The alternative to hourly pay or piecework, is a salary.

Comment: An obvious one is billing them based on the estimate and not the actual amount of time used. This forces you to estimate accurately or go bust.

Answer (score 13):

**Time box**

Give us two weeks and we'll show you what we can do.

This is the mantra of Agile.  The idea is to shape the work to fit in a time box. Have something of value presentable by the end of the time box and you've shown the customer what you can do with that time.

This way you aren't predicting the future and constantly ending up wrong. You're showing how far you got. The customer can then decide if they want more work done. And, well, since it's been two weeks it's a good time to ask for a check so your people can get paid.

While this isn't for everyone it's certainly an alternative to estimates.

In my experience estimates are mostly consequence free guesses. When they decide to get serious about this stuff they call them bids. Those have legal consequences.

Comment: "Bidders" invariably have more experience with software than their clients, and therefore they always refuse risk and impose all the possible consequences back onto the client. The ranks of those which don't, are constantly chastised by grievous loss and thinned by bankruptcy.

Comment: @Steve and that's why construction jobs use architects. It's not just about buildings that look pretty in pictures.

Comment: @candied_orange heh, where I live, they say that's why you ask the civil engineers and not the architects

Comment: @candied_orange, we are unfortunately still in the era of the "grand follies" and "spruce gooses", except that it is the management of rich corporations, rather than personally rich individuals, who commission them.

Answer (score 6):

The leading alternative to estimation is the use of flow metrics and probabilistic forecasting. If you have historical data on cycle time and throughput, you can use statistical modeling to determine how long it will take to complete the work with a given level of accuracy.

However, this approach will require some effort to break down the work into right-sized pieces. With a large enough sample size of historical work, some variation in sizing can be ignored, but you need to have the work reasonably sized. You probably won't be able to take a raw request and use your flow metrics to determine how long it will take. This may be a bigger investment of time than it takes you to refine the work sufficiently to provide an estimate, but the quality of the predictions will likely be higher.

Since the data is based on history, there are also several things that can disturb the data. Any changes in context could make the historical data less relevant. This includes changes to the team, the problem domain, the tools and technology, and the processes and way of working. If you have a large enough set of teams within your organization, you may be able to try to get some organizational historical data, but it would be less accurate than a single, relatively stable team over the life of a long-lived product.

Comment: I wonder if "context changes" like those mentioned (different customers is probably the worse one) can be isolated and removed from the equation, to avoid disturbs (deviations)  in your forecasting and turn those into margins of error. These might fall short I know but it's better than giving an optimistic estimation which, in 99% of the cases, will never happen. For example, giving each customer different margins, depending on what kind of customer is, its background, current context, relationship with the organization, etc. Say "customer", say "stakeholders".

Comment: @Laiv That's kind of what I was alluding to in the last paragraph. I'm not sure how good the resultant data would be and if you'd have a margin of error that was actually any better than traditional estimation techniques.

Comment: Flow forecasting is estimation in disguise though. The estimation is hidden in the part where you divide a request into right-sized pieces (and frequently that's exactly how estimation is made more methodical, even when not actually using flow-based stats to forecast). I'm not saying that doing the stats is never helpful, but the fundamental way it can go wrong is the same as with estimation; it's "the things we didn't know that we didn't know" that get you, because they can cause an essentially unbounded error in prediction. Unbounded errors don't average away over time (unlike ±X% errors).

Comment: @Ben I've worked with teams that shifted from "estimate work" to "right-size work". The conversations moved from "let's throw a number up" to discussions about what stakeholders want and how the system should behave, which reduced the unknown unknowns. With a large enough sample size, you don't need to worry about equal sizing the pieces, but focusing on thin slices of valuable work, which helps frame those planning and design discussions. This, in my experience, makes flow forecasting more accurate, and accounts for undiscovered work as soon as it's slotted in to a queue or backlog.

Comment: @ThomasOwens Yes, that's definitely helpful; as I mentioned, plenty of teams do estimation of a request **by** breaking it down into right-sized pieces. My point is, the biggest source of error in "breaking a request down into small pieces and then adding the estimates for those up" is the same as the biggest source of error in "breaking a request down into small pieces and then using historical stats to predict when that many pieces will be down". It's that some of the pieces will turn out not to actually be small, or missed entirely. And that effect does **not** average out.

Comment: @Ben [The Law of Large Numbers](https://www.neilkillick.com/blog/noestimates-part-3-the-palm-off) says that the size of pieces will average out over time. A reasonable attempt at decomposing the work (which is ongoing over time - it's not a once-and-done activity to decompose the work) will be sufficient to let you predict. The missing work will be the problem, but that just shifts the completion date as you add more items. But improving your data about throughput will also shift the completion date.

Comment: @ThomasOwens No it does **not**. It would if just as many errors were on the low side as on the high side (and by the same range of amounts). But that's not what happens. When you're so extremely lucky that the task is only a tenth of the size you thought it would, you've saved 90% of your "right size". But that's absurdly fortunate, almost never happens. Whereas that's outweighed by a single instance of a task that takes twice as long as you planned (which loses you 100% of your right size), which is not that rare.

Comment: @Ben If you have 100 units of work or 1000 units of work, you may have a couple that are much larger than the others and a couple that are smaller. It balances out. If it didn't then the use of flow metrics wouldn't work, but the experience of myself and many others across many efforts and many teams show that flow metrics are more reliable. I'd check out the work of Dan Vacanti and his work in agile metrics, predictability, and forecasting for a lot of examples.

Answer (score 4):

As candied_orange notes, the mainstream alternative is to timebox the result.  You basically deliver whatever you have completed after a certain amount of time and charge for the time.  The issue is that a lot of customers probably won't accept this arrangement.  Think about if you were having some work done on your house, would you pay a contractor for whatever they deliver in 2 weeks?  How do you know that they won't just slack off?  That requires a lot of trust and if you are managing a business, entering into such a deal is highly questionable.

One thing that strikes me in your question is "Work is generally broken down into small chunks, with estimates being provided for each of these, rather than large pieces of work all at once."  This is problematic and an example of one of the most common misconceptions I see around estimation: that estimating more granularly will improve the estimates by increasing precision.  The problem is that while you might increase the precision (likely with [false precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_precision)) it's almost surely going to reduce your accuracy.  As an analogy, let's say I asked you to measure a length of a long straight board.  You have two unmarked measuring sticks of known length: one is a meter long and the other 10 centimeters.  Which one is going to give you a more accurate answer?  The 10 cm stick has higher precision but requires more measurements and the errors in each measurement will tend to accumulate.  You will get a more accurate answer with the longer stick.  In fact, one trick to increase the accuracy of any estimate is to lower the precision.  For example, if try to predict the location of a person in the world, I'm much more likely to be correct if I give a larger area as my answer.  You should really limit the precision of your estimates to what is useful.  If you are estimating in hours because that's what you charge by, that's a mistake.  The client is unlikely to be making their decision hinge on the cost of a single hour of work.  They are probably thinking in multiples of money e.g. $10K or $100K, maybe millions if it's a big project.

The other big issue I see with estimates is that people are either unaware or disregard the fact that an estimates are inherently ranges/distributions.  Often people just give a single number and never provide any guidance of the precision.  That's not an *estimate*, that's a *guess*.

Lastly, I also find it frustrating that people ignore prior art around this kind of thing.  PERT, for example is a useful technique with a sound mathematical foundation.  I'm not saying everyone should be using a formal process like PERT for their projects, but understanding things like how to add up variances across a number of estimates and use those to predict a delivery time with 98% confidence can really help with wrangling the issues you describe.

Comment: Your point about false precision is a good one, but your other point that increasing granularity reduces accuracy is contrary to my own experience. The reason is that the actuals follow a probability distribution that looks a lot more like a log-normal distribution than a symmetrical normal distribution. When you combine several items the median of the sum is greater than the sum of the medians; take 4 tasks estimated 8 hours each. The median for all four together is always > 32 hours. This incidentally is the reason that Gantt charts created from PERT _always_ under-estimate the total time.

Comment: @IanGoldby I take your point and there's more to my argument than I am able to unpack in an answer like this.  Combining the medians of the individual is how the mean of the critical path is created so I'm not sure about the distinction you are making there.  I would also argue that the mean of the critical path would be expected to be too low about 50% of the time even if your estimates were correct on average and the distribution was perfectly normal.  That's one of the big issues with just adding up a bunch of tasks estimates without ranges and saying that's the estimate.

Comment: The other problem which is a little orthogonal to the statistical aspects is that hours are a terrible basis for estimation. When someone says 4 hours for a task, they are thinking about focused hours, not the 4 hours they will spend looking for documentation, debugging some typo etc. It's really better to think in terms of days or weeks e.g. how many of this kind of task can be completed in a day. The problem isn't that more granular is always worse, it's that you need to use the appropriate 'stick'.  For example, estimating in minutes wouldn't work better than hours, right?

Comment: Yes, I agree with you about not using hours (unless you are estimating tasks that really do take no more than a couple of hours each). The issue about means and medians is a little more complicated. Greater granularity (smaller tasks) helps reduce the overall uncertainty because errors can cancel. It also forces the dev to think more. However, for such a highly asymmetrical distribution as this, we think in terms of median (50% of the time a task like this will be done within 1 day), not the mean. A simple sum of the medians to get the total is **too small** due to the asymmetry.

Comment: ... so you have to treat each estimate as a suitable probability distribution (log normal works well) and combine the distributions appropriately. (I've heard of software that does this stochastically based on past estimates and actuals.) Low/medium/high is sufficient for estimating the uncertainty on a particular task.

Comment: @IanGoldby Right, I understand what you are saying about asymmetric distributions.  My point was that even if it was perfectly symmetrical (I agree it is not) where the mean == median, you would expect the mean critical path to be low nearly 50% of the time.  And your comment "Low/medium/high is sufficient for estimating the uncertainty on a particular task" is exactly what I am getting at.  Few people will do that.  They just give a single likely estimate with no context of the range.  In my experience the worst case is often very large relative to the expected case...

Comment: @IanGoldby ... So if we capture that high end of the estimate, we can use it to get to what people really want: something like a98% chance it will be complete in a certain time.  If you don't get the upper and lower range, you don't have the necessary information for that. What people tend to do is just add up the likely estimates and say 'here's the estimate' but people are expecting something with a much higher level of confidence so you get situations where estimates are just padded arbitrarily.  I'm simply advocating for more rigor and I think I am aligned with you at a high level here.

Comment: @IanGoldby One last technical note, in PERT the tasks are assumed to follow a beta distribution.  I'm not super-strong with statistics but I'll dig into the log normal distribution.  The nice thing is that the standard PERT approach has an easy shortcut to find the std. dev.  I'm not sure if the potential complications of using something else would be worth it.  The inputs (e.g. dev estimates) are pretty unreliable in my work and the result can't be taken too literally.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139065/discussion-between-ian-goldby-and-jimmyjames).

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, a company would capture metrics/measurements of how long projects take. How "big" or "complicated" was project X? Additionally, reviews (sometimes called "post mortems") would be held after the project's completion.

One software consultancy I worked at required all work to be measured in 15 minute intervals. They were able to prove how long it would take to develop things (whether "just a web page", or significant redesign & upgrades to the sites involved). This way they could always show the customer what things were going to cost and the customer was able to say whether those changes made financial sense (or not). They were very uptight about billing and every code check-in had to point to a project that was paying for that code (even internal "refactoring" had to have a project to bill to). They were too uptight for my preference, but I believe that they were one of the few places I worked where they gave estimates that were reasonably accurate. They had multiple clients each having different software needs & solutions.

Your agency should have been collecting metrics. How "big" (nowadays, usually called "points") each task was. And measuring how much each developer billed (or documented working) each of those tasks. Eventually, you can say "developer X says this is 4 points" and from experience that means developer X is going to take 6 working days to complete that task. If developer Y said 4 points, that takes them only 4 days. That does not mean X is better than Y. It just means that for X, "4 is this big" means "6 days" and for Y, "4 is that big" means "4 days". Too many mismanagers would think something like "Y is a better developer because they get it done 2 days quicker" and they would be wrong.

If you never capture estimates and examine them afterwards, then estimating project times is useless. This is the state that most companies I've worked for were in - never looking at those estimates ever again. For those companies, deadlines were determined by managers looking at calendars.

[Function Points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_point) and [COCOMO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COCOMO) are reasonably well known estimating systems. There are books about them that you can read. I've made simple Excel spreadsheets with Function Point estimators so when a manager goes "how big is that", I can punch in a few numbers, multiply by what I think the complexity is, and get a reasonably close answer.

Comment: *"They were too uptight for my preference"* - the real problem with these models, is that the bureaucracy and rigidity alone is a significant cause of expense. I also suspect what they actually impose upon clients is a discipline of simplicity - by making simple things swingeingly expensive, they discourage clients from asking for more complexity like they would if asking for more seemed cheap, where uncontrolled growth of internal complexity is actually the main threat to the health of an efficient and powerful client.

Comment: @Steve "is that the bureaucracy and rigidity alone is a significant cause of expense" a very good point, I think.  Sometimes organizations will reduce the variability of their work by making everything take (much) longer.  That might be a conscious and correct choice but I think sometimes it happens by accident.

Answer (score -1):

You can charge in a outsourcing or agency fashion. ie X developers at rate Y working full time on the clients project.

Of course the client will still want a rough estimate, at which point you can also charge for a project manager to work out the estimates for them.

This model maintains the trust between your client and you by allowing the client to manage the resources (more) directly. You can sell the idea by saying that it can reduce costs by removing the priced in risk of underestimating, the possibility of dropping features that turn out not to be needed and/or allowing changes in spec during the project at zero cost.

Answer (score -2):

*Just don't give estimates*

---

It's as simple as that really... If your client demands estimates, you explain why it's a futile false economy.

At that point you explain the benefits of an estimateless system such as Kanban, and then offer to do a small subset of the work to demonstrate how well it works. You can always give them heavily couched ballpark estimates under the proviso that they will be wrong and they're for very rough guidance only.

If they still insist on proper estimates then you either suck it up and give them some estimates or you go find a less archaic client.

Comment: Archaic?  How many customers are going to be gullible enough to take you on, at an hourly rate, without even an estimate of how long it will take?  Because they will strongly suspect that you will drag the project out indefinitely, until they run out of money to pay you.

Comment: Well given I work for a large tech consultancy with tens of millions a year in revenue and we don't work on estimates... Your point just doesn't really hold water.

What's the point of doing estimates when everyone accepts that they're always wrong?

Comment: The customer has its planning and a lot of expectations. In my 15y of experience working for consultancies, no customer has shown a glimpse of interest in agile methodologies. They all want something and want it now. They always convenience themselves about the deadlines. Moreover, many demand the Gantt! Maybe you are lucky, but definitively yours is not a common case.

Comment: @Laiv - We're just picky about who we take on as clients, but we're certainly not short of work. Our whole schtick is that we follow XP and agile practices, it's a huge selling point. We've even got government contracts being run off agile.

Then again, this is likely a regional thing, I can see other countries being very different.

Comment: @SimonB, the flaw in your logic is that, if we accept the estimate given is both non-binding and perhaps quite wrong, then how does the giving of an estimate stop the vendor dragging the project out? The task the client faces is to judge the character of the vendor's management - to assess whether that management can be *trusted not to* drag the project out, even in circumstances where their doing so might go unsuspected, and would certainly go unpunished even if suspected.